# Highcharts React update animations with datetime axis

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm using the official `highcharts-react-official` package in my React 16.6 app, to render a **columns** chart. I want to enable animations there and for the initial animation everything works fine. But when I update my data (used in the config via props), I don't get a growth animation. I'm using a `datetime` xAxis here and this seems to be part of the problem.

You can find a sandboxed environment here (notice that there isn't even a growth, but the state gets updated correctly?): https://codesandbox.io/s/38xwxr81lp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts for performance uses the reference to the original data array. In your code, you edit the second level of the data: `lastColumn.value[1] += 100;` which causes that there are no changes in the options during update.

This example presents similar situation: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tf1csqeo/

The solution is to clone your data before modifying it:

```
handleClick = () => {
  let newData = this.state.data.map(x => x.slice());

  if (newData[newData.length - 1][1] < 450) {
    newData[newData.length-1][1] += 100;

    this.setState(
      {
        data: newData
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/6xv0kr3v0n

As you can see, the animation works correctly.

Comment: It's really tricky to get around that, with nested objects as props that are getting mapped to highcharts config. :/ But it work's this way now, thank you! :)

Comment: When I attach a linear gradient to your example, the animation gets disabled again: https://codesandbox.io/s/z2oy0xwrol. Could this be a bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi @Ole Bläsing, Yes, you are right, that seems to be a Highcharts bug related with the gradient color update. I reported the issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10216 As a workaround, you can remove the `color` property from the series options before `setState`.